# Converting simplegui to pygame

Tags: python, pygame

So originally I was asked to make a matchmaking game in python using simplegui. I now need to change all the code to pygame. My code so far:

```
import pygame
import random

num_list = []
exposed = []
state = 0
first_pick = 0
second_pick = 0
moves = 0

# helper function to initialize globals
def init():
    global num_list, exposed, moves
    moves = 0
    num_list = [i%8 for i in range(16)]
    random.shuffle(num_list)
    exposed = [False for i in range(16)]
    pass



# define event handlers
def mouseclick(pos):
    global state, first_pick, second_pick, moves
    this_pick = int(pos[0] / 50)
    if state == 0:
        first_pick = this_pick
        exposed[first_pick] = True
        state = 1
        moves += 1
    elif state == 1:
        if not exposed[this_pick]:
            second_pick = int(pos[0] / 50)
            exposed[second_pick] = True
            state = 2
            moves += 1
    elif state == 2:
        if not exposed[this_pick]:
            if num_list[first_pick] == num_list[second_pick]:
                pass
            else:
                exposed[first_pick] = False
                exposed[second_pick] = False
            first_pick = this_pick
            exposed[first_pick] = True
            state = 1
            moves += 1
    l.set_text("Moves = " + str(moves))
    pass


# cards are logically 50x100 pixels in size
def draw(canvas):
    offset = 50
    hor_pos = -25
    for i in range(len(num_list)):
        hor_pos += offset
        canvas.draw_text(str(num_list[i]), [hor_pos, 50], 30, "White")
    exposed_pos = -50
    for i in exposed:
        exposed_pos += offset
        if not i:
            canvas.draw_polygon([(exposed_pos, 0), (exposed_pos + 50, 0), (exposed_pos + 50, 100), (exposed_pos + 0, 100)], 10, "White", "Orange")


pygame.init()

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
size = [800,100]
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
done = False
# Program Loop -----------------------------------------------------------------
while done == False:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: # If clicked close
            print ("User asked to quit.")
            done = True # Exits loop

    pygame.display.set_caption("Match-Making Game")


    # register event handlers
    pygame.set_mouseclick_handler(mouseclick)
    pygame.set_draw_handler(draw)
    pygame.add_button("Restart", init)
    l=pygame.add_label("Moves = 0")

    pygame.start()
    # Updates screen

    clock.tick(10)
    # Limits to 10 Frames Per Second

pygame.quit()
```

The problem with the code above is in the program loop. I need to convert the "simplegui" pieces of code into pygames. Can anyone help me find the pygame equivalent of set_mouseclick_handler(), set_draw_handler(), add_button(), add_label(), and start(). If you can, can someone try getting this code to function and help me out with the code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Pygame is a python wrapper for the Simple DirectMedia Layer. SDL is not a graphical user interface library. If you want to have such functionality you could use [existing](http://www.pygame.org/wiki/gui?parent=index) gui libaries for pygame, or create your own.

If you only want the functionality of buttons and labels, you could implement it yourself.

To start, you should create a Button that will have a draw method, to draw itself onto the screen, it's position on screen, and size and a function variable that will be set to a function via set_mouseclick handler.

You can get the mouse coordinates like this:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        print(event.pos)
```

You can then pass this to all the buttons, so they can determine if they had been pressed.
If they were, they call their mouseclick handler.

Another issue that you have to address is text. You can use the pygame [font](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html) module to draw text. There are many questions on SO covering text gereration in pygame so I won't get into that.